# Gather all IP addresses of a host as a vector

Tags: c++, array, c++17, networking

I have the following working code to get IPv4/v6 addresses from host names:

```cpp
#include <array>
using std::array;

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

#include <netdb.h>

#include <stdexcept>
using std::domain_error;

#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using boost::asio::ip::address;
using boost::asio::ip::address_v4;
using boost::asio::ip::address_v6;

vector<address> getAddresses(string const &hostname)
{
    struct addrinfo req = {.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC, .ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM};
    struct addrinfo *pai;
    int error = getaddrinfo(hostname.c_str(), nullptr, &req, &pai);
    if (error)
        throw domain_error("Could not resolve host name.");

    vector<address> addresses;

    for(struct addrinfo *info = pai; info != nullptr; info = info->ai_next) {
        if (info->ai_family == AF_INET) {
            auto ipv4socket = reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr_in*>(info->ai_addr);
            auto ipv4addr = address_v4(htonl(ipv4socket->sin_addr.s_addr));
            addresses.emplace_back(ipv4addr);
        } else {
            auto ipv6socket = reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr_in6*>(info->ai_addr);
            auto ipv6base = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr);
            array<unsigned char, 16> bytearray = {
                ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr[0],
                ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr[1],
                ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr[2],
                ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr[3],
                ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr[4],
                ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr[5],
                ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr[6],
                ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr[7],
                ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr[8],
                ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr[9],
                ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr[10],
                ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr[11],
                ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr[12],
                ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr[13],
                ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr[14],
                ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr[15]
            };
            auto ipv6addr = address_v6(bytearray, ipv6socket->sin6_scope_id);
            addresses.emplace_back(ipv6addr);
        }
    }

    return addresses;
}

int main()
{
    auto addresses = getAddresses("heise.de");

    for (auto ipa : addresses)
        cout << "Address: " << ipa << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I find the conversion fom `uint8_t[16]` (`ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr`) to `std::array<unsigned char, 16>` a bit verbose.
I also considered doing it in a for-loop, but this would still seem cumbersome to me, somehow.
I tried `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` to no avail.
Is there a possibility to do this conversion in a simpler way, preferably a one-liner?

Comment: You object to a for loop, would you object to `std::copy` or something similar?

Comment: I would not. I am explicitely looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you that the copying of data from `s6_addr` seems cumbersome.  I would instead just cast without copying:

```
auto& bytearray = reinterpret_cast<std::array<unsigned char,16>&>(ipv6socket->sin6_addr.s6_addr);
```

(If we had needed to copy, we could change `auto&` to plain `auto`).

Apart from this, the variable `ipv6base` is never used, so should just be removed.

Comment: Thank you so much. Such a noob mistake from me. I forgot the ampersands. :facepalm:

Comment: Oh, I've done the same myself from time to time.  Easy to get wrong, and very hard to spot what's incorrect!

Comment: Using a type-change cast like that, with modern compilers you have to beware of _undefined behavior_.   The old tricks using a union or type puns are now technically illegal.  How is this not falling into that trap?

Comment: Good point @JDługosz.  I can't prove that this is legal.  I think it's _likely_ to be safe in this context.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast "Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType, the behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true: ... AliasedType is std::byte, char, or unsigned char: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes."